# How do iOS apps know your region?

Tags: ios, ip, region

In the pc world they can only use one identifier which is IP address, but I just recently discovered iOS apps use 2 or more criteria to find your region. I found something called advertising identifier that those apps are using. Can anybody explain the concept please? What kind of identifier is this and how can I mask my device?

Answer (score 0):

UDID, UUID, MAC Address,IDFA-identifierForIdentifier,IDFV-identifierForVendor

But unfortunately, all of the above indicates that the device identification number unique in IOS7 in either banned, or reinstall the program after two acquired identifier is not the same.

IOS system because the data are stored in sandBox inside, once you delete App, sandBox would cease to exist. Fortunately, there is one exception, that is, keychain (keychain).